# Displaying Images(from folder) and tables(from database) In the same Crystal Report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I am using VS2010(winform), and Access database ,In my crystal report I am successfully showing tables from database by creating `DataSetPatient.xsd` file and using below code  ,now I want to display Images from the particular folder/folder path into same report ,as I am new to crystal reports please can anyone show me step by step how can I do this

```
public partial class ViewR : Form
    {        
        DBHandling db=new DBHandling();

        public ViewR()
        {
            InitializeComponent();             
        }

        private void ViewR_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CrystalReportP objRpt;
            // Creating object of our report.
            objRpt = new CrystalReportP();
            DataSetPatient ds = new DataSetPatient(); // .xsd file name
            DataTable dt = DBHandling.GetPatient();
            ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
            objRpt.SetDataSource(ds);            
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;          

        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

First:  created a New Column name ("Image") in a datatable of the dataset and change the DataType to System.Byte()

second: Read Image File Convert into Binary array and store it into your data table,

third : now you data table has Data from database and Image data from Path image , assign this datatable to database, and Report Source :

code:

```
private void ViewR_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalReportP objRpt;
        // Creating object of our report.
        objRpt = new CrystalReportP();
        DataSetPatient ds = new DataSetPatient(); // .xsd file name
        DataTable dt = DBHandling.GetPatient();
        dt = GetImageRow(dt, "YourImageName.Jpg"); 
        ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
        objRpt.SetDataSource(ds);            
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;          

    }
```

//By this Function You can Append Your Image to Datatable

```
private DataTable GetImageRow(DataTable dt, string ImageName)
    {

        try
        {

            FileStream fs;
            BinaryReader br;

            if (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ImageName))
            {
                fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ImageName, FileMode.Open);
            }
            else
            {
                // if phot does not exist show the nophoto.jpg file 
                fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "nophoto.jpg", FileMode.Open);
            }
            // initialise the binary reader from file streamobject 
            br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // define the byte array of filelength 
            byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.Length + 1];
            // read the bytes from the binary reader 
            imgbyte = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32((fs.Length)));

            dt.Rows[0]["Image"] = imgbyte;


            br.Close();
            // close the binary reader 
            fs.Close();
            // close the file stream 




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error handling 
            MessageBox.Show("Missing " + ImageName + "or nophoto.jpg in application folder");
        }
        return dt;
        // Return Datatable After Image Row Insertion

    }
```

Note: first: Here I take path as Application Statrup path , you can take any path you want.
Second: this is runTime Image loading ,
third: here i also Explain how to convert image into byte array so, it will useful when you want to store your image in database